# Restrict git / code access to front-end developer

Tags: git, security, bitbucket

I want to add a front-end developer to my project, but don't want to give full access to my bitbucket repository as I want this person to only work on front-end related code (TWIG template engine, Twitter Bootstrap). Also, I do not want to have the risk of my full source code to be leaked.

How would I ideally solve this? What is the best way to only give fractional code access for front-end development (e.g. using bitbucket's git repository)?

Would it make sense to export my template files (& fill them with dummy content) to have my developer work on those instead? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your project structure but in the most cases you need the complete project to run the code. In that case it makes no sense to restrict access to only the "Frontend" section.

In Bitbucket you can only give access to the whole repository or rights for a single branch.

So if you have want to split your application to Frond- and Backend you have to create different repositories for all sections.

Comment: Thank you! I just added that I use twig and bootstrap, as well as the question of whether it would make sense to just export the views filled with dummy content. Would be great, if you have thoughts on that too.

Comment: It depends, does the front-end developer need the twig markup? I don't think so. Give them the rendered views (HTML) to modify and then you integrate that into the Twig templates.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ that make not so much sense to do the work twice... that is no efficient way to work on an project.